# Jackson Parsing with java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I really hate to do this, but I have two questions: can Jackson 2.7.3 parse the following url and can do I have to parse every part of the JSON?

Here is the code I am working with so far:

```
public class Song {
private String tracks;
private String album;
private String images;

public void setTracks(String tracks){
    this.tracks=tracks;
}
public void setAlbum(String album){
   this.album= album;
}
public void setImages (String images){
    this.images= images;
}
}
```

And

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=track:" + finalSong + "%20artist:" + finalArtist+"%20" + "&type=track").ignoreContentType(true).get();
                String title = String.valueOf(doc.body().text());

                Song obj = mapper.readValue(String.valueOf(title), Song.class);

            } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();

  return null;
}
```

All I need is the "preview_url" and one of the "images" url towards the top
the JSON is located at https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=track:Ready%20To%20Fall%20artist:rise%20against%20&type=track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you necessary need to map your Json response into a class?

If not you can get your desired values as following e.g. for `preview_url`

You can use `readTree` to map the `json` result into a tree of nodes.

There after you can use `findPath` to search for the property you looking for.

In the case of `image` it contains an array. Thus if you want to select a specific item from that list you get use `get` to select the specific item you want.

**example**

```
JsonNode readTree = mapper.readTree(body);

for (JsonNode node : readTree.findPath("items")) {
    System.out.println(node.findPath("images").get(2));
    System.out.println(node.findPath("preview_url"));
}
```

Comment: Would there be a way to select a certain "url" such as the 64 x 64 image url?

Comment: yes that's possible. I noticed also that your example url would yield an array of items which contains two albums. I'm going to update my answer in a moment

Comment: It should just be one album

Comment: Sorry I'm not that good in explaining, But you could read the documentation for Jackson API for further information http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes ;)